Typing for tuple or list of tuples in recursive function
Here is an example I wrote.
from typing import Tuple, List


def performances(
    pt: Tuple[float, float] | List[Tuple[float, float]]
) -> float | list[float]:
    if isinstance(pt, list):
        output = []
        for pt_i in pt:
            output.append(performances(pt_i))
    else:
        output = pt[0] + pt[1]
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # This work as intended
    t1 = performances((1, 2))
    print(t1)

    # This work as intended
    t2 = performances([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
    print(t2)

    # This work while I was expecting it to throw a TypeError
    t3 = performances((1, 2, 3, 4))
    print(t3)


How can I apply type checking in this case to be sure I only accept a list of tuple with two elements?
I also tried without the Tuple and List type from typing, just using list[tuple[float, float]] but the result it the same.
And:
from typing import Tuple, Iterable

type Point = Tuple[float, float]

def performances(pt: Point | Iterable[Point]) -> float | list[float]:
...

But same.
There is probably something I don't understand about typing but I don't know what.
Thank you.

Are you using type checker to validate this? Python inherently do not check for type errors.

I am using Pytest for some unit testing of my code, and this particular test passes while I had test rejected for type errors before (I think? Maybe it is not the case).

In python, type annotations are optional, and unfortunately, are allowed to be completely incorrect. Separate applications like mypy or pyright allow you to use the annotations to perform static analysis of code, and under the assumption of the annotations being correct, will warn you of errors. However, at runtime, these annotations are typically completely ignored (baring libraries like Pydantic which use annotations for logic control). Pytest is only responsible for execution of test statements and checking asserts. Pytest does not validate any type annotation correctness.

If you want to be able to check for those types at runtime, this question might be useful: extracting data from typing types

Possible duplicates: What are type hints in Python 3.5?, Possible to enforce type hints?, Python >=3.5: Checking type annotation at runtime, Is it possible to make python throw errors if the type of the argument passed to the annotated function doesn't match the one specified?, etc.

what exactly is your question here? What is the problem?

I thought type hinting will raise TypeError, now I understood I need to check it with a type checker like mypy. Now I have the errors shown in the answer below, and I am wondering how to fix them.

This really should be two different functions. performance takes a tuple and returns a float, and def performances(xs): return [performance(x) for x in xs].

The output types have two distinct outcomes based on the parameters. pt: Tuple[float, float] leads to float, whereas pt: List[Tuple[float, float]] leads to List[float].
Mypy and other static analysis tools have no good way to determine which input shape should lead to which output shape. This leads to errors when calling append(performances(pt_i)), as your static analysis tools will think you are trying to create a List[Union[float, List[float]]]
A good way to remedy this is to use @overload from the typing module.
from typing import Tuple, List, overload


@overload
def performances(pt: Tuple[float, float]) -> float:
    ...


@overload
def performances(pt: List[Tuple[float, float]]) -> List[float]:
    ...


def performances(
    pt: Tuple[float, float] | List[Tuple[float, float]]
) -> float | list[float]:
    if isinstance(pt, list):
        return list(map(performances, pt))
    return pt[0] + pt[1]

Using this strategy, static analysis tools can more easily validate the inputs to their actual outputs. See my earlier comment on your post for why Pytest alone is not enough to validate this scenario.
